# function does not work until I click on the screen during run time

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, nstimer

I want to show an animated image once the view is loaded for a few seconds then hide it and view 2 other images, I have used an array to animate the image then set a timer to call function onTimer repeatedly ,inside this function I check if the image is animated for once, if so stop the timer and view the 2 other images

it works fine when I run the project except that the 2 images do not appear until I click on the screen!

her is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
outline.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"traffic.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"], nil];

[outline setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
outline.animationDuration = 4;
[outline startAnimating];

 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0/30.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}

-(void) onTimer {

if (![outline isAnimating]  == TRUE){ // if animation has been played once, do something
    NSLog(@"animation stopped, do something");
    rannan.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rannan.png"];
    outline.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"outline.png"];
    [ timer invalidate];

    // do something
}
}
```

it looks like for some reason isAnimating is not set to TRUE until I click on the screen when the project is running

hope I will find an answer for this one :)

Answer (score 0):

I just wonder why you fire your timer every 1/30 of second. You set your animation to 4 seconds so you can just fire your timer after 4 seconds.

A way to check if your view is no longer animating:

```
CALayer *presentationLayer = (CALayer*)outline.layer.presentationLayer;
if(![presentationLayer animationKeys])
{
    NSLog(@"animation stopped, do something");
}
```

Comment: it seems there is a problem with the code you wrote above it says at the first line:"property presentationLayer cannot be found in forward calss object CALayer" 
and at the if statement it says: "Reciever type 'CALayer for instance message is a forward declaration"

Comment: I made the timer check every 1/30 of a second in case the animation freeze or something for any reason, in this case it won't finish after 4 seconds